# is a convex function continuous on a hilbert space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, convex-optimization

A convex function on $R^n$ is continuous. Does the result hold on infinite dimension on a Hilbert/Banach space ?

Comment: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842527/continuity-of-bounded-and-convex-function-on-hilbert-space) is possible a duplicate?

Comment: @RanWang almost but there is a bounded assumption on the question in your link, not in mine